# How do I get "res.fields" to stop coming back as "undefined" in my application?

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I am working on a project using multer to upload multiple files. To do this, I am using upload.fields in a controller file, the code looks like this:

**tourController.js**

```
const multerStorage = multer.memoryStorage();

const multerFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  if (file.mimetype.startsWith('image')) {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb(new AppError('Not an image! Please upload images only.', 400), false);
  }
};

const upload = multer({
  storage: multerStorage,
  fileFilter: multerFilter
});

exports.uploadTourImages = upload.fields([
  { name: 'imageCover', maxCount: 1 },
  { name: 'images', maxCount: 3 }
]);
```

In the next function, where I resize the images, I console.log res.files, but it comes back as undefined in my terminal output. Here is the code where I console.log res.files. It follow the code that I posted directly above:

```
exports.resizeTourImages = (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(res.files);
  next();
};
```

I tried using upload.array, but couldn't get that to work as expected either. I'm not sure if the problem could be with a different part of the application. Here's where the function appears in the middleware stack in the route file:

**tourRoutes.js**

```
router
  .route('/:id')
  .get(tourController.getTour)
  .patch(
    authController.protect,
    authController.restrictTo('admin', 'lead-guide', 'guide'),
    tourController.uploadTourImages,
    tourController.resizeTourImages,
    tourController.updateTour
  )
```

I'm at a loss as to why I can't get this work. If helpful, I have all of the code uploaded to GitHub here:

https://github.com/christopherbclark/mynatours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#fieldsfields), `res.files` is undefined because multer populates the `files` under the `req`-object. You need to change it to:

```
exports.resizeTourImages = (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.files);
  next();
};
```

Comment: I feel stupid now. THANK YOU for your help, much appreciated!